# Map.setTransformCenter (PointF center) stop working

Tags: here-api

After I upgraded the android Here SDK to 3.3, Map.setTransformCenter (PointF center) stop working, is that a known issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tried the new 3.3.1 release? Also is this using the Premium or Starter edition of the HERE SDK?

Comment: I am using 3.3.0, Premium.

Comment: The issue is the map fragment will be resized and then also need to change the centre of map, sometimes it works but sometimes not, I think its the timing, so when should I call Map.setTransformCenter ?

Comment: just need to know when is the correct time to set the transform centre, I tried with both OnMapRenderListener and OnTransformListener , unreliable either

Answer (score 1):

For the use case you describe in the comments, you can try setting the transform center during the `OnMapRenderListener#onSizeChanged(...)` callback. If it is still unreliable here, perhaps try setting after a short delay following this callback (e.g. repost a runnable to the UI thread which calls `setTransformCenter` after receiving `onSizeChanged` callback).

Comment: Thanks! will add a delay

Comment: MapRenderListener#onPreDraw() would also be a good place to put the transform center calculations.